# How do I write to multiple output files within a foreach loop in perl?

Tags: perl, foreach, output, histogram

I have two different input files from an atom probe:

1) POS file with 4 columns, x y z i (which I convert from binary)

2) RRNG file with information about atoms in the sample and their corresponding "i" values.

I am able to extract all the necessary information from the input files and store them into arrays but my problem comes when I try to save the information to multiple output files.

Here is what I have so far:

```
foreach $j (0..50) {    #there are 51 peaks in this data set
    $min = $range_min[$j];
    $max = $range_max[$j];
    open(POS,$ARGV[1]);
    while(sysread(POS,$xyzi,16)) {   #input is binary
        @row=unpack("f>4",$xyzi);
        if ($row[3]>$min && $row[3]<=$max) { #if "i" value within
                                             #the given range
            open(FILE,">file$min_$max.txt");
            print FILE join(" ",@row[0,1,2,3]) . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to search the POS file for all data points with an "i" value between `$min` and `$max` and store those points as x, y, z, and i columns in the output file, but I want to do that for all 51 ranges of "i" values.

This code works fine for one peak without the foreach loop but I don't want to hard-code this for 51 different ranges.

I hope this is clear. Thanks.

Comment: trying to understand, but your code doen't contains any `i`. So from where the `i` comes? (in the code `3` is the `i`?) And for what you want use the `i`?

Comment: @jm666 Oh sorry, the "i" value is the data in the fourth column of my POS input file which is represented by `$row[3]` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example:

```
open my $fin,   '<', $inputfile or die $!;
open my $fout1, '>', $filename1 or die $!;
open my $fout2, '>', $filename2 or die $!;

while( my $line = <$fin> ) {
    print $fout1 $line;
    print $fout2 $line;
}
```

Just open multiple filehandles and print to each.

Comment: Thanks that worked great! All I needed to do was change how I used `open` to be more like what you said and it worked. I am still new to perl so there are lots of fundamentals that I still need to learn.

Comment: @IzaakWilliamson Well, the 3-arg open is better practice. the `open FILE` syntax creates a global filehandle -- that could be possibly be causing problems.